# Can you use past perfect tense in general past sentenses?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

e.g. I usually started my day with the thing that had woken me up.
Or you must use past perfect only in specific situations.

Comment: Your example sentence doesn't quite make sense; what are you trying to convey in your phrase?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, what you'd like to know is if a sentence such as the following is possible:

*When I was younger, I could only watch television if I **had finished** my homework first.*

The past perfect (*had finished*) is fine here. The entire scenario refers to a repeated, iterative situation in the past, not to a single event.

To summarize, the past perfect serves to locate a situation before some other point or situation in the past, regardless of whether that situation occurred once or was a habitual, iterative past situation.